# The equivalent operator to closing with 200 iterations in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am using `opencv` to find the major area in an image from the camera from the production line.

raw image:
[image]

result:
[image]

As one of the critical operations, I found `closing` with a 3x3 kernel and iterations as 200 times being a very robust solution.

However, this will make the processing time very slow, almost 0.2s, which is not acceptable in the production line vision algorithm.

I wonder if there is equivalent things we can do to reduce the processing time. For example, reducing iterations and increasing the kernel size. But I didn't find a perfect pair that can achieve the same good result.

Is there a theoretical reference based on which we can say the following are mathematically equivalent?

`closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3)),  iterations = 200)`

`closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, ?,  iterations = 50)`

Code:

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def crop_hcc(FILE, PLOT = False, MARGIN = 592):
    bgr = cv2.imread(FILE)    
    img_r = bgr[:,:,0]
    _, img_gray = cv2.threshold(img_r, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)# + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))    
    opening = cv2.erode(img_gray, element, iterations = 2)    
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, element,  iterations = 200)
    #opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img_gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, element,  iterations = 30)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    max_contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)    
    M = cv2.moments(max_contour)
    x = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    if PLOT == True:
        X = bgr.copy()
        cv2.drawContours(X, [max_contour], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
        plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
        plt.imshow(X)
        plt.show()
    x_start, x_end = x - MARGIN, x + MARGIN
    y_start, y_end = y - MARGIN, y + MARGIN
    CROPPED = bgr[y_start:y_end,x_start:x_end,:]
        
    return CROPPED
```

Comment: Have you tried resizing your image to make it smaller, applying the closing, and resizing back to original scale?

Comment: It might also help if you posted what you would like your result image (i.e. what features you are looking to extract) to look like given the input image you posted. As for working on downscaled image, it all depends on what features you are after and whether downscaling preserves those or not.

Comment: @John, I think you asked the question a few days back about finding circles, perhaps the center of the disk?

Comment: Test result: resizing (down-scaling) the image first works stably. But I need to be very careful with the iteration values. Thanks. @eldesgraciado

Comment: @Knight Forked, Yes and after testing on a huge amount of images, the most simplistic approach (many many closing operations) works most robustly.